# A trigger fires on a table, but the select on the table returns null. How can I create the code to be able to access the row that fired the trigger?

Tags: select, plsql, transactions, database-trigger

A trigger fires on a table, but the select on the table returns null. How can I create the code to be able to access the row that fired the trigger?

I have the following in the trigger:

```
begin
  dws_edi_api.init_edi_message(message_id,order_no',supplier_no');
end;
```

This fires on update of the column row_state in the table out_message_tab
The event fires OK but when in the procedure dws_edi_api.init_edi_message_line I do a select c08 from out_message_tab where message_id = message_id_ (variable from the trigger). it returns null. 
I assume the change hasnt been committed. I have tried adding a commit as the first line in my code to force the change to commit but that doesnt help. I have tried adding a dbms_lock.sleep(!0) but that doesnt help either.
 I add the code to the procedure in the "show some code box"

```
 procedure init_edi_message_line(message_id in number) is
    pragma autonomous_transaction;

    message_id_  number;
    order_no_    varchar2(20);
    supplier_no_ varchar2(20);
    c08_         varchar2(200);

    cursor c1 is
      select c08
        from jdifs.out_message_line_tab
       where message_id = message_id_
         and name = 'HEADER';

  begin
    -- dbms_lock.sleep(10);

    message_id_ := message_id;

    open c1;
    loop
      fetch c1
        into c08_;
      exit when c08_ is not null;

       insert into jdifs.jdws_temp_line_tab
    values
      (message_id_, '2', c08_, '4');
    commit;

    END LOOP;

    close c1;


  EXCEPTION
    WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
      -- Do something
      null;

    WHEN OTHERS THEN
      null;

  end init_edi_message_line;
```

EDIT:

Hi, no this didnt solve the problem unfortunately,
I will try again to explain as thourougly as possible.
 I have a trigger on the table called out_message_line_tab. When a row is created in that table it contains a big number of columns.

the ones that are interesting to me are message_id(which is a sequential number), order_no (P123456), supplier_no(11242), linenumber(1), part_no (F1524).

When the trigger fires data needs to be fetched from that table (and a table "connected to this table" in this case, out_message_tab.

So the trigger is on out_message_line_tab, but it isnt enough to send the values in the trigger to the procedure, since I need some data from the other table as well. 
The primary key between the tables out_message_tab and out_message_line_tab is message_id

So my problem is how to do the select from out_message_tab where message_id = message_id(primary key from out_message_line_tab

When I do, it just says no data found. I assume its because it has not been commited yet.

I hope this is clearer.

Answer (score 0):

Your procedure `init_edi_message_line()` is defined using `pragma autonomous_transaction`. That means it executes in *a completely separate session*. Consequently it cannot see any of the uncommitted data in the session which fired the trigger.

If you want `init_edi_message_line()` to process data from that session your triggers needs to pass **everything** to the procedure as an argument. However it's not clear exactly what you're doing - is `out_message_line_tab` the table which owns the trigger? - so I can't guarantee that it will be easy for you to make the necessary changes.

Comment: Hi, yes the autononous pragma is there since I tried without it and it didnt work. So I added it and added sleep so it would wait for the commit. And yes out_message_line_tab is the table that has the trigger

Comment: If this doesn't solve your problem - and it sounds like it doesn't - then please **edit your question** to explain exactly what you're your trying to achieve, including table structures, input data and expected output. It's always easier if you provide your business rules instead of asking us to reverse engineer them from some snippet of code.

Comment: Thank you for that, I added some clarification (I hope):)